# Display user profile the second time he uses the application

Tags: android

Here's the case, the first time the user uses the application and fills in his important personal data on the edittexts, it automatically should be stored in SQLite db. The second time he uses the application, the details he input should be displayed on edittexts and need not be blank fields. How am I going to do that?

the only thing that I already is this.
for my method to checkvalues:

```
           private void checkValues(){  

           String f1 = etFname.getText().toString();
     String f2 = etLname.getText().toString(); 
     String f3 = etMname.getText().toString();
     String f4 = etAge.getText().toString(); // int
     String f5 = etWeight.getText().toString(); // int
     String f6 = etHeightFt.getText().toString(); // int
     String f7 = etHeightIn.getText().toString(); // int
     String f8 = rgGender.toString();
     String f9 = spBloodType.toString();
     String f10 = spBodyType.toString();
     String f11 = etDOB.getText().toString();

     if ( ( f11.isEmpty() || f1.isEmpty() || f2.isEmpty() || f3.isEmpty() || 
         f4.isEmpty() || f5.isEmpty() || f6.isEmpty() || f7.isEmpty() ||
         f8.isEmpty() || f9.isEmpty() || f10.isEmpty() || f11.isEmpty() ) ) 
     { 

         viewErrorBlankToast();

     }
        else
        {

            boolean didItWork = true;       

            try{

            AddUser entry = new AddUser(Profile.this);
            entry.open();

            entry.createEntry(f1, f2, f3, Integer.parseInt(f4), 
                    Integer.parseInt(f5), Integer.parseInt(f6), Integer.parseInt(f7), 
                    f8, f9, f10, f11);

            entry.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;

                // call for viewing custom toast
                viewErrorToast();
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){

                viewProfileSavedToast();
                }
            } // end try-finally statement       

        } // end of if-else statement

} // end checkValues method
```

and my adduser.java code is:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class AddUser {
// user table column names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
private static final String KEY_MNAME = "mname";
private static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
private static final String KEY_HEIGHTFT = "heightft";
private static final String KEY_HEIGHTIN = "heightin";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String KEY_BLOODTYPE = "bloodtype";
private static final String KEY_BODYTYPE = "bodytype";
private static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_user";
private static final String TABLE_USER = "tblUser";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_MNAME + " TEXT" +  KEY_LNAME + " TEXT" + KEY_AGE + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT" + KEY_HEIGHTFT + " TEXT" + KEY_HEIGHTIN + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT" + KEY_BLOODTYPE + " TEXT" + KEY_BODYTYPE + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_DOB  + " TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public AddUser(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public AddUser open(){
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String fname, String mname, String lname, int age, int weight,
        int heightft, int heightin, String gender, String bloodtype, String bodytype,
        String dob) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
    cv.put(KEY_MNAME, mname);
    cv.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
    cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
    cv.put(KEY_HEIGHTFT, heightft);
    cv.put(KEY_HEIGHTIN, heightin);
    cv.put(KEY_GENDER, gender);
    cv.put(KEY_BLOODTYPE, bloodtype);
    cv.put(KEY_BODYTYPE, bodytype);
    cv.put(KEY_DOB, dob);
    return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_USER, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] column =
        //  new String[]{ KEY_EXERCISEID, KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DISEASEID };
            new String[]{ KEY_ID };
    Cursor c = 
            ourDatabase.query(TABLE_USER, column, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";
    int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    //int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    //int iDisease = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DISEASEID);

    /*
    for( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
        result = result + c.getString(iID) + c.getString(iName) + c.getString(iDisease) + "\n";
    } // end for loop*/

    for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
        result = result + c.getString(iID);
        //result = result + c.getString(iName);
        //result = result + c.getString(iDisease);
    }

    return result;
}

public String getDataName(){

    String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_FNAME };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query(TABLE_USER, column, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);

        /*
        for( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString(iID) + c.getString(iName) + c.getString(iDisease) + "\n";
        } // end for loop*/

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString(iName);
            //result = result + c.getString(iName);
            //result = result + c.getString(iDisease);
        }


    return result;
}


public void updateEntry(long lId, String mFName, String mMName, String mLName, int mAge,
        int mWeight, int mHeightft, int mHeightin, String mGender, 
        String mBloodtype, String mBodytype, String mDob) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();

    cvUpdate.put(KEY_FNAME, mFName);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_MNAME, mMName);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_LNAME, mLName);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_AGE, mAge);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_WEIGHT, mWeight);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_HEIGHTFT, mHeightft);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_HEIGHTIN, mHeightin);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_GENDER, mGender);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_BLOODTYPE, mBloodtype);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_BODYTYPE, mBodytype);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_DOB, mDob);
    ourDatabase.update(TABLE_USER, cvUpdate, KEY_ID + " = lId", null);
}

public String getName(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to store this information using Shared Preferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that lately, but I'm about to reference the personal details to other modules of my application.

Comment: With Shared Prefs you can still access the data from any of your activities.

Comment: If I'm to use sharedprefs, can I still edit it?

Comment: Yes, with the SharedPreferences Editor, check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a boolean value into a SharedPrefs file indicating that the user has filled out their personal information.

Something like this

```
public class A extends Activity
{
       private static final String MY_KEY = "some_string";
       private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
       private boolean loggedIn;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.home);

       myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);

       loggedIn = myPrefs.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);  //default to false if the value has not been set

       if(loggedIn)
       {
          //do stuff        
       }
      else
       {
           //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And when the User actually fills in their information for the first time

```
   myPrefs.edit().putBoolean("loggedIn", true).commit();
```

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: Hello what if I'm about to view it as I finish saving user profile?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: if the user already fills in information, the next time he goes to profile activity, it should be displayed automatically without even pressing a button to do so?

Comment: Yes you can accomplish this, in my answer posted above you check if the user is logged in, if they are then you do stuff like myEditText.setText(myPrefs().getString("userName", null);

Comment: I appreciate really your help. But my problem is not about logging in to the activity but saving just a personal details to an activity and use that as reference for future use.

Comment: This is exactly what SharedPrefs will do, you can save variables for future use, you can edit them, and you can delete theme.